# How do I add a Checkbox into a #{{link-to}} Helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

**The problem:**
I have a table with a link-to within an each. I want the first cell of each row to have a checkbox strictly for toggling. I can display the checkbox, but I can't get it to let me check it.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Things</th>
    <th>Stuff</th>
<th></th>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each myArr as |item|}}
          {{#link-to 'application' tagName='tr' }}
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>

      <td>{{item}}</td>
      <td> Something</td>

          {{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- I don't want to go to the route
- The checkbox needs to toggle
- The checkbox doesn't need to hold a value (can be destroyed on page refresh)
- Using the `{{input}}` helper makes no difference

I have a twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/bc53d499687ad8bdc902be5cd7d77f48

Comment: Why you put them in `{{link-to}}` ?

Comment: :)) Your boss is wrong.`{{link-to}}` is for creating links. If you want something else maybe you should use another thing

Comment: You want action on click row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate as components.

Please look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/85a4489a43d77e9779b14e368a08bc6a)

Comment: Thanks. That's a good solution. But how would I implement it in an array with any number of items. Like items from a database? Same thing?

Comment: Just tried it in production and it works. I ended up foregoing the component and just using an action in the controller. So it's `<td {{action 'rowClicked' thing.id}}>`. I should have mentioned that it's still Ember 1.10. Sadly just shy of a lot of cool stuff. Great job on providing a clear example!

Comment: @D.Breen Cool. Congrats